# Sorting a WPF Data Grid Text Column With MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Below is a DataGridTextColumn definition from my WPF datagrid with the converter difination and the converter code. Can someone please tech me how to sort this column, I believe I need to use Icomparer but after trying to adapt online example my attempts have failed. If you could give an explanation in VB.Net that would really help - thanks.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:DurationConverter x:Key="MyDurationConverter"/>
    <c:DistanceConverter x:Key="MyDistanceConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Width="70" x:Name="Duration">
  <DataGridTextColumn.Binding >
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyDurationConverter}">
        <Binding Path="StartDate" />
        <Binding Path="EndDate"/>
        <Binding Mode="OneWay" />
      </MultiBinding>
  </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
 </DataGridTextColumn>

Friend Class DurationConverter
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

    Friend Function Convert(values() As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
        Return (CType(values(1), DateTime) - CType(values(0), DateTime)).ToString

    End Function

    Friend Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetTypes() As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your converter only calculates `TimeSpan` between `EndDate` and `StartDate`, in your case, it will be much easier if you create another public `TimeSpan` property in your object, lets call it `Duration`, which will return `EndDate - StartDate` and bind that directly, without `IMultiValueConverter`, to your `DataGridTextColumn`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Width="70" x:Name="Duration" Binding="{Binding Path=Duration}">
```

For presentation it will be converted `ToString()` but will still compare it as `TimeSpan` and you will be able to sort by it like any other column

Comment: Thanks very much dkozl for your help, the datagrid is bound to a filtered view of a database table, from my code in the 'Duration' property how can I get access to the current values of 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'. Can I somehow pass these to the function when I set up the binding? Thanks again dkozl.

Comment: Is it Entity Framework that you use to get data from database?

Comment: Sorry dkozl it's not a view on a database table I bind to it's a view of an in memory data table.

Comment: So why you cannot add `Duration` property to the object where you have `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties?

Comment: I have bound my grid directly to the dataview, 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' are columns in this view.

Comment: did you try adding calculate column to your source `DataTable`: dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Duration", typeof(TimeSpan),"EndDate - StartDate"))?

Comment: That's a good idea and won't take me to much to do, thanks so much for your help dkozl.